# Execute ruby script from cron

Tags: ruby, cron, rvm, tiny-tds

My script uses mysql, tiny_tds, fileutils, and net/ftp.  Running on ruby 1.9.3.  It works perfectly fine when I run it from inside the folder.

However, when I add it to cron tab, tiny_tds constantly fails.  I dont know if any of the other gems fail as I can't get passed this error:

> require': no such file to load -- tiny_tds (LoadError)

I tried executing it from the same shell that crontab would use, and I get that error.

The entire script is just 1 file.

I'm new to ruby so my knowledge is limited in setting up the environment the right way.

In the head of the file I have

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby
    require "mysql"
    require "fileutils";
    require "tiny_tds"  
    require "net/ftp"
```

In short, I get a list of Jobs from mysql, compare that against MsSQL,  FTP files over and update mysql again when jobs are done.

And I need to run this from cron.

After researching for a bit, I tried to set set the gems as global, however, I think that may not have worked.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: did you find a resolution for this?

Answer (score 5):

This is because the environment variables you have on the command line are not set when crond executes you code.  The usual suspects are `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and aliases that are set when you login.

You can see what crond does:  using `crontab -e`

```
* * * * *  set > /tmp/setvals
```

create the above entry.  let it run for a while.  Go back into `crontab -e` and remove that new entry.

Compare what is in `/tmp/setvals` with what your shell gives you when you issue the `set` command on the command line.  You can then take steps to modify things for your cron job's environment.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways for RVM to cooperate with cron, if you use script then the simplest is just to use RVM - which means do not use system ruby `#!/usr/bin/ruby` - just put in the first line `#!/path/to/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p392/ruby`

you can use aliases to prevent hardcoding one ruby path in a script:

```
rvm alias create my_app 1.9.3
```

and then in script header (first line):

```
#!/path/to/rvm/wrappers/my_app/ruby
```